# how do i make this so everything can use it? C++

Tags: c++, public, findwindow

im somewhat new to c++ so i don't know how to do this but my main point in recoding this is to incress the speed of my program, i have been coding a project
and my code is:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"*window's name*");
DWORD th32ProcId;
HANDLE hProc;

GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &th32ProcId);

hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, th32ProcId);
```

so i have about 20 functions that all use that at the start of each time i run them and the value will never change so is there some way i can declare and then set it at the value of what it finds?

my code is set up like this

one main file int main() and it's just set on a loop and it keeps retesting and calls the other functions and everything else is in a void *name*() and i have 2 int *name*()

im using VC++ 2008.

*edit*
no :| i just want a way i can share thoses values with all of the program.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to implement some kind of caching.  That would be fine and you can create a cahe with an `std::map`.

You would probably have something like:

```
std::map<std::string, HANDLE> cacheMap;
```

You can then check the `cacheMap` to see if a result exists.  It if does exist you don't need to call the function, if it does not exist you would then call the function and add the result to your `map`.

Comment: :| no not really what i wanted ty anyway

Comment: I would not recommend to share handles across different programs.